# Calling a Namespaced JavaScript Function from Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, namespaces, externalinterface

Can I use ExternalInterface to call a namespaced JavaScript function?

```
//JavaScript
foo.bar = function(baz) {}

// AS3
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call('foo.bar', baz);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `ExternalInterface.call` is a little misleading. it states the first parameter must be a function name, which is not the whole truth. it can be any string that can be evaluated as a proprer JS expression. In fact

```
ExternalInterface.call(func, param_1, ... , param_n);
```

is equivalent to

```
eval(func)(param_1, ... , param_n);
```

so you may just as well do the following

```
ExternalInterface.call("function (foo) { alert(foo); return true; }","test");
```

this technique is sometimes used for [Flash JS injection](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/745/1/JavaScript-and-VBScript-Injection-in-ActionScript-3/Page1.html). hope this clarifies things ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Yes you can.

Comment: The question was purely theoretical, so in the way that I called it above is correctly for calling a namespaced function?